# Server reports a 200 status for non-existent pages

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I use CMS DEW POWER. When I enter the wrong address, the user see a page 404, but the server returns a 200. My notfound.phtml:

```
<div class="text">

            <div class="lblock"><b>Requested URL was not found</b><br>

            <br>

            When trying to connect following error:<br>

            <ul class="list1">

                <li>Non-existent URL</li>

            </ul>

            <br>

            One element of the requested URL is incorrect. Possible problems:<br>

            <ul class="list1">

                <li>Missing or incorrect access protocol (should be "http://" or similar)</li>

                <li>No host name</li>

                <li>Illegal characters in path</li>

                <li>Illegal characters in the hostname, underscores banned</li>

            </ul>

            </div>

            <br>

            <br>

            <br>

            <div class="end">&nbsp;<br>



            &nbsp;</div>        <br><br><br>

    </div>
```

I tried to insert at the beginning of the document the following code, but it did not help.

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. In **SiteController** my **notfoundAction** looked like this:

```
function notfoundAction() {
        $this->view->notfound = 1;
        $this->view->section_name = '404';
        $this->view->inner_content = $this->view->partial('notfound.phtml');
        return $this->page_inner();
    }
```

And I added HttpResponse:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
```